# Conditional formatting ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a dashboard, where a field displays values of different types. Something like this

Row     Average of 3 years
1           Percent
2           Count
3           Count
4           Count
..
7           Percent
9           String (e.g. ABC : 100, EDF: 2900)
10          Percent

I wrote an expression

```
=IIF(Fields!mos_id.Value = 1, FormatPercent(Fields!Average_prev_3_years.Value,2),
IIF(Fields!mos_id.Value = 6, FormatPercent(Fields!Average_prev_3_years.Value,2),
IIF(Fields!mos_id.Value = 7, FormatPercent(Fields!Average_prev_3_years.Value,2),
IIF(Fields!mos_id.Value = 8, FormatPercent(Fields!Average_prev_3_years.Value,2),
IIF(Fields!mos_id.Value = 10, FormatPercent(Fields!Average_prev_3_years.Value,2),
Fields!Average_prev_3_years.Value))))
```

The percentages and the counts show up fine but where I had strings, I get the #Error. What am I missing?

Comment: The Report format is something like this. The Average field holds data in different formats like counts, percentages, text inputs, whose display is controlled by the mos_id field.

Comment: [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun 'store_name.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.
Preview complete -- 0 errors, 1 warnings